# How to set up the correct url ? (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have two classes in model.

```
class Ebuy_Fields(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    rfq_id = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    rfq_title = models.TextField()

class Ebuy_Detail_Fields(models.Model):
    rfq_id_final = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    rfq_id_title_final = models.TextField()
```

In views.py,

```
def ebuy_detail(request,rfq):
    # unique_bid = get_object_or_404(Ebuy_Detail_Fields,rfq_id_final=rfq_id_final)
    unique_bid = Ebuy_Detail_Fields.objects.filter(rfq_id_final__icontains=rfq)
    context = {'unique_bid':unique_bid}
    return render(request,'rfq-display.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
path('ebuy/<rfq>', ebuy_detail, name='ebuy_detail'),
```

In templates,

```
<td data-label="RFQ Id"><a href = "{% url 'ebuy_detail  i.rfq_id %'}">{{ i.rfq_id }}</td>
```

After clicking, this link, it should open the detail view of the Ebuy_Detail_Fields.

`rfq_id` and `rfq_id_final` are same and it should be matching.

Comment: This <td data-label="RFQ Id"><a href = "{% url 'ebuy_detail'}">{{ i.rfq_id }}</td>
 Should be this. <td data-label="RFQ Id"><a href = "{% url 'ebuy_detail' %}">{{ i.rfq_id }}</td> also you are supposed to pass rfq as parameter to the above url. can you show the view? because I don't really know what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes, rfq as parameter, if rfq_id and rfq_id_final then it should show the detail view.

Comment: then why are you not passing rfq in the url tag?

Comment: I have passed the rfq in the url now, but still data is not being displayed `{{ unique_bid.rfq_id_final }} `is not being displayed

Answer (score 1):

First of all your

```
<td data-label="RFQ Id"><a href = "{% url 'ebuy_detail %'}">{{ i.rfq_id }}</td>
```

is wrong. Because you need to close that tag.(`<a ...>...</a>`)

Secondly, your URL should look like this,

```
path('ebuy/<int:rfq>/', ebuy_detail, name='ebuy_detail'),
```

And finally, in template your [`url template tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url),

```
<td data-label="RFQ Id">
    <a href = "{% url 'ebuy_detail' rfq=i.rfq_id %}">
        {{ i.rfq_id }}
    </a>
</td>
```

You need to pass the object id to the URL as an argument. And how you used single quotes in `{% url ... %}` is wrong too.